# Javascript pass a string value from a tag to a input box

Tags: javascript, forms, function, calendar, href

Hi I am trying to pass values into my calendar input box. There are 3 links in a `<p>` tag that on click I would like the values in that href to go into the input box as a test Data for the calendar. Currently I tried setting the hrefs to an onClick event that once one the test dates are clicked it will the function testData(). In the testData() function I put it so that it will get the value from the href and store it into the input box with the ( id = textDate). Then when the person clicks submit, the calendar will give the proper information on a calendar. The calendar works it is just the passing of the href value to the input box for testing that I am having issues with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table td{width:25px; background-color: rgba(215, 44, 140, 0.14);}
        table{border:1px solid black;}
        .first{background-color:black; color:white;}
    </style>

    <script>

        function GenerateTable(month, day, year)
        {
            var myMonth = month;
            var myDay = day;
            var myYear = year;
            var myMonthInteger =0;
            var table = "<table><caption>" + myMonth + " " + myYear + "</caption><tr><td></td></tr>";
            var firstDayOfTheMonth = ["Su", "Mo" , "Tu", "We","Th", "Fr", "Sa"];
            var arayMonthDaysAmount = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];

            switch(myMonth)
            {
                case "January":
                    myMonthInteger = 0;
                    break;

                case "February":
                    myMonthInteger = 1;
                    break;

                case "March":
                    myMonthInteger  = 2; 
                    break;

                case "April":
                    myMonthInteger = 3;
                    break;

                case "May":
                    myMonthInteger = 4;
                    break;

                case "June":
                    myMonthInteger = 5;
                    break;

                case "July":
                    myMonthInteger = 6;
                    break;

                case "August":
                    myMonthInteger = 7;
                    break;

                case "September":
                    myMonthInteger = 8;
                    break;

                case "October":
                    myMonthInteger = 9;
                    break;

                case "November":
                    myMonthInteger = 10;
                    break;

                case "December":
                    myMonthInteger = 11;
                    break;

                default:
                    myMonthInteger = 1;
                    break;
            }

            var myDate = new Date();
            myDate.setFullYear(myYear);
            myDate.setMonth(myMonthInteger);
            myDay = myDay.replace(',','');
            myDate.setDate(myDay);
            var startDate;
            var myCounter = 0;
            startDate = myDate.getDay();
            var flip = false;

            for(cnt = 0; cnt < 7; cnt++) //ROWS
            {
                table += "<tr>";

                    for(cnter = 0; cnter < 7; cnter++) //COLS
                    {

                        if(cnt == 0)
                        {
                            table += "<td class = \"first\">" + firstDayOfTheMonth[cnter] + "</td>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(cnter == startDate+1 || flip == true)
                            {
                                flip = true;

                                if(myCounter < arayMonthDaysAmount[myDate.getMonth()])
                                {
                                    myCounter +=1;
                                    table += "<td>" + myCounter + "</td>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    table += "<td></td>";
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                table += "<td></td>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    table += "</tr>";
                }

                table += "</table>";    
                document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = table;
            }

        function getMyDate()
        {
            var enteredDate = document.getElementById("textDate").value;
            var myCurrentDateArray = enteredDate.split(" ", 3)
            var myMonth = myCurrentDateArray[0];
            var myDay = myCurrentDateArray[1];
            var myYear = myCurrentDateArray[2];

            GenerateTable(myMonth,myDay,myYear);
        }

        function TestData()
        {

            var test = document.getElementByID("test2").value

            document.getElementById("textDate").value = test;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "setMyDefault()">

    <form>
        <legend>Enter a date: (month dd, yyyy)</legend>
        <input id = "textDate" type = "text" value = "November 14, 2014" pattern = "[a-zA-Z]{3,}\s[0-9]{1,2}[,]\s[0-9]{4,4}"/>
        <button type = "button" onClick = "getMyDate()">Generate Calendar</button>
    </form>

    <p>Test Data: <a href = "" onClick = "TestData()" id = "test2" value = "h">Nov 11, 2012</a> | <a href = "" name = "test1" value = "Mar 21, 2012">Mar 21, 2012</a> | <a href = "" name = "test0" value = "Sept 6, 2012">Sep 6, 2012</a></p>
    <div id = "myTable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help, I hope I gave enough information for you. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a anchor tag to trigger the function you might want to set the href to href="#" to stop the tag from navigating you to a different page or refreshing the current page. To target an element you can use multiple methods.
If you want to target a specific element then you can use

```
document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML;
```

document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML will target the content within that tag.

document.getElementById("test2").value will target the value attribute of the tag.

If you want your function to by run by multiple elements then i suggest using

```
<a href = "#" onClick = "TestData2(event)"
```

-

```
   function TestData(e)
    {
        var YourResult=e.target.innerHTML;
    }
```

[Demo JSBin](http://jsbin.com/woxequmoke/1/edit?html,js,output)